# JLabel - Can't get two integers to add

Tags: java, swing, jlabel

I'm trying to create a basic Java program with JLabel that adds two numbers.

But for some reason, when I try and add the two numbers, int3 doesn't change

EDIT: I've added an event, however its saying int 1, 2 and 3 cannot be found

```
private partA() 
{

super("Part A");;
setSize(500, 500);
setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
setResizable(true);
setVisible(true);
setLayout(new FlowLayout());


JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea();


JLabel number1Label = new JLabel("Number 1: ", JLabel.CENTER); //NUM1LABEL

JTextField int1 = new JTextField(15);                   //NUM1BOX

JLabel number2Label = new JLabel("Number 2: ", JLabel.CENTER); //NUM2LABEL

JTextField int2 = new JTextField(15);                   //NUM2BO

JButton addition = new JButton("Add");                    //ADDBUTTON

JLabel int3 = new JLabel("", JLabel.CENTER);

GridLayout grid = new GridLayout(3,3);
setLayout(grid);
add(number1Label);
add(int1);
add(number2Label);
add(int2);
add(addition);
add(int3);
setVisible(true);
}

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

    String name = e.getActionCommand();

    if(name.equals("Add")) {
        int num1 = Integer.parseInt(int1.getText());
        int num2 = Integer.parseInt(int2.getText());
        int result = num1 + num2;
        int3.setText(Integer.toString(result));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to the wonderful world of event driven programming. Unlike procedural programming, where one instruction follows another in a linear fashion, in event driven programming something happens and you respond to it, in a non-linear fashion.

What you need is some way for the user to tell you that they'd like to perform the calculation, after they've filled in the fields.

I recommend you start by having a look at [How to use buttons](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/button.html) and [How to write an action listener](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/actionlistener.html) which will give the details you need to allow the user to tap a "calculate" button and perform the operation

Comment: Oh right. So basically  I need it so, "when the button is clicked, execute this block of code"

Comment: @TambohMcDougal Yes. Have a look at the tutorials, see what you can create, I won't rob you of the chance to discover the solution on your own, as the reward is undefinable, and you will learn more from it. If you have trouble with a particular concept, come back and we'll provide you with some more guidance

Comment: Thanks, i've read a bit more into it and added some code but having another issue